# goLang pass struct to function (args interface{})

Tags: go, type-assertion

Here is my code
http://play.golang.org/p/h0N4t2ZAKQ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Msg struct {
    Message string
}

func print(y interface{}) {
    z, ok := y.(Msg)
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(z))
    fmt.Println("Value of ok ", ok)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("Message is "+ z.Message)
    }
}

func main() {

    foo := new(Msg)
    foo.Message="Hello"
    fmt.Println("Messege in main "+foo.Message)
    print(foo)

}
```

When I run it z.Message does not print Hello
Not sure why. Can someone clarify?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of `foo` in your program is `*Msg` (pointer to Msg), not `Msg`. You need to cast `y` to `*Msg` in `print` (http://play.golang.org/p/MTi7QhSVQz):

```
z, ok := y.(*Msg)
```

Alternatively you can use `Msg` type for `foo` (http://play.golang.org/p/XMftjVtzBk):

```
foo := Msg{Message: "Hello"}
```

or

```
var foo Msg
foo.Message = "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program, one thing that you will notice is that value of "ok" is false and that's the reason for your print statement in if not getting executed. If you  remove "ok" from  z, ok := y.(Msg), you will see the error that Go is throwing while executing this assert statement. With ok, Go will not panic and will return false if assertion fails. Which is happening in your case.

The reason for asserting failing is, expected, type in print method is Msg(main.Msg), but passed is pointer i.e. *main.Msg. You will see this error when you don't use "ok"

So one way is to

```
print(*foo)
```

Or

```
z, ok := y.(*Msg)
```